# Meaning of "seems promising"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I just heard some one saying "it seems promising". I did not get its sense. Where and how is being used?  I tried googling as well but could just find meaning of promise (agreeing on doing / saying something), how and where to use it.

Comment: [Seem](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seem):to appear to be [promising](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/promising): indication of future excellence or achievement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this definition:

> [*promise*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/promise) : 2. Indication of something favorable to come; expectation: *a promise of spring in the air*.

If someone says something *seems promising* then they are saying, 1. that if it happens it will be good, and 2. that they think there appears to be a "good" chance that it will happen.

Answer (score 2):

"*It seems promising*" is actually an very easy phrase to understand. It just means that it(whatever you were talking about) has a very high possibility of happening in the future.